# What's the word for the thing that an observer observes?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Does a word exist in English which describes the person/object being observed?

Let's say that I am observing Mike. I am an *observer* in this case.

What is Mike called in relation to me? *Observant*?

**EDIT**

I came up with this question when trying to name the `server 2` which is being observed by `server 1` (see image). Server 1 is making sure the server 2 is working properly, having enough disk space, responding to requests in appropriate time and being virus-free.

[image]

Comment: ***Why*** are you observing Mike? If you work for a law enforcement agency and you're just doing your job, he might be called [***a person of interest***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/person-of-interest). In general, we don't really have a specific word for ***thing observed***, because unless you're blind, that's pretty much ***everything***. But you can single out a specific ***focus** [of attention]*.

Comment: I added an image to explain the origin of my dilemma. I have two servers, one of them (observer) is constantly observing another one to make sure it's working properly.

Comment: It's potentially misleading to introduce the idea of a *person* (Mike) being "observed" here. You're not really talking about "observing" as an activity carried out by (and ***on***) people. More relevant to you is [***A system monitor** is a hardware or software component used to monitor **system resources** and **performance** in a computer system.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_monitor) Where I personally would say the things being monitored are best referred to as ***metrics*** (things which can be measured & monitored).

Answer (score 4):

**observed** (n.)

> That which is observed or made the subject of observation.
> Usually in explicit opposition to *observer*; in 19th cent. frequently in allusion
> to quot. 1604.
>
> 1604   W. Shakespeare *Hamlet* iii. i. 157   The glasse of fashion,
> and the mould of forme, Th' obseru'd of all obseruers
>
> 1994   R. Wallace *Time's Fancy* 28   It is just good physics how,
> merely by observing, the observer changes the observed. (OED)

---

> He had been the Observer in Africa; now he was the Observed. [Joan
> Mark; *The King of the World in the Land of the Pygmies*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_King_of_the_World_in_the_Land_of_the/xFuhGWeAHa0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22he%20was%20the%20observed.%22&pg=PA222&printsec=frontcover) (1998)

> He was **the observed** of a good many observers. [Joseph Rose; *They
> Called Him Wild Bill*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20was%20the%20observed.%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APq-WBud0Meb_infWzx6XVjXpywIscdHNw:1647435081204&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwir0rj21cr2AhUjZjUKHatfBSI4ChCnBXoECAEQIw&biw=976&bih=451&dpr=1.5) (1979)

> Wherever Smoke moved, he was **the observed** of many eyes. [Jack
> London; *Smoke Bellew*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Smoke_Bellew/CTgjAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22he%20was%20the%20observed.%22&pg=PA173&printsec=frontcover) (1912)

> She was **the observed of all observers** (as Shakespeare wrote of
> Hamlet), but she was also a constant observer of herself and had
> constantly to present to the world an idealized icon of herself as the
> Queen. [Donald Spoto; *The Decline and Fall of the House of
> Winsor*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Decline_and_Fall_of_the_House_of_Win/bra4vjnLQcMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22she%20was%20the%20observed.%22%20hamlet&dq=%22she%20was%20the%20observed.%22%20hamlet&printsec=frontcover) (1996)

> Ophelia is continuing to express her feelings towards Hamlet’s
> “o’erthrown (163)” mind. “**Th' observed of all observers**, quite,
> quite down! [Tyanna Pleasant; *Hamlet: Close Reading*](https://scienceleadership.org/blog/hamlet--close_reading-4#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CTh%27%20observed%20of%20all%20observers,think%20about%20her%20at%20all.)

Comment: @Mark Note, as the definition calls out, all these examples use it only in close proximity to "observer." It would be a bit odd to use it in isolation.

Comment: @DjinTonic How about running for moderator? Two seats are open.

Comment: @Xanne I much appreciate being asked, but I'm too new and not sure being a moderator is for me.